# How to create a dictionary of dataframes for each column category

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dictionary

I have a dataframe that looks like this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([[201801, 0.5, 273.4, 'Fleet'], [201801, 0.34, 277.4, 'Drake'], [201801, 0.75, 255, 'Bay'], [201802, 0.97, 244.4, 'Fleet'], [201802, 0.54, 267.4, 'Drake'], [201802, 0.89, 235, 'Bay']], columns = ['time', 'windspeed', 'winddir', 'site_name'])
df
```

[image]

I want to create a dictionary of dataframes where the dictionary key is the site_name column and then the value is rest of the dataframe (i.e. the other 3 columns).

How can I do this please?

I do create this dataframe from combining 4 arrays into a dataframe earlier on, so if it is easier, then I could create the dictionary of dataframes from the arrays instead?

Comment: Please provide the dataframe in a text format. In particular, please read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20109391/17769815).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

GroupBy object, when iterated over, gives back the grouper keys along with the group dataframe; therefore a dictionary comprehension is possible. The grouper is also included in that subframe, so we drop that:

```py
grouper = "site_name"

d = {name: sub_df.drop(columns=grouper) for name, sub_df in df.groupby(grouper)}
```

to get

```py
>>> d

{"Bay":      time  windspeed  winddir
 2  201801       0.75    255.0
 5  201802       0.89    235.0,

 "Drake":      time  windspeed  winddir
 1  201801       0.34    277.4
 4  201802       0.54    267.4,

 "Fleet":      time  windspeed  winddir
 0  201801       0.50    273.4
 3  201802       0.97    244.4}
```

Comment: You can shorten to this `d = dict(tuple(df.groupby('site_name')))`.

Comment: thanks, but need to drop the grouper

Comment: `dict(tuple(df[df.columns.difference(['site_name'])].groupby(df['site_name'])))` maybe?

Comment: oh yeah, can use drop instead of difference perhaps? `dict((*df.drop(columns=grouper).groupby(df[grouper]),))`